# Error generating sequence in HSQLDB with Hibernate using hbm2ddl

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am getting an error while generating a sequence for an id field in HSQLDB. The mapping file is configurated like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ddol.rtdb.dto.Configuration" table="RTDB_CONFIGURATION">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="CONF_ID" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">CONF_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="configurationDate"
            type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="CONF_DATE" />
        </property>
```

It works when I use the same mapping with oracle, but does not generate the sequence when used with HSQLDB for testing. Is there anything else I should add to the mapping?

The error I am getting when I try to insert something into the table is:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user has no privileges or object not found: CONF_ID_SEQ
```

HSQLDB version is 2.2.8, Hibernate version is 3.6.10

Comment: Well, it's clear that the sequence CONF_ID_SEQ doesn't exist in HSQLDB, have you created it?

Comment: No, I expect hbm2ddl to create it, as it does for oracle

Comment: I don't know why but clearly, it hasn't been created.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=991963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the sequence(CONF_ID_SEQ - if it doesn't exists) and make sure that you have `"grant"` permission for that.
Alternatively, you can create a `"synonym"` for the sequence and give `"grant"` permission for all the users or to the specific users you want to. Then it should work.

```
    E.g  
    Consider, You are creating Sequence as "dbauser". Now, some other "user"(who don't have access) trying to use it,  
then u will get "user has no privileges" error.  
    In that case you can use above strategy.
```